# the_excerpt() doesn't return the Excerpt field content

Tags: excerpt

The problem I'm having is that `the_excerpt()` isn't returning the content from the post's "Excerpt" field. Instead, it's returning the first 55 words of the post, as though the "Excerpt" field is empty.

My code is very simple - inside the loop, I have:

```
if( has_excerpt() ) {
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    the_content();
}
```

Is there something that needs to be done to tell wordpress to use the "Excerpt" field.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [the example from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_excerpt)?

```
if ( ! has_excerpt() ) {
      the_content();
} else { 
      the_excerpt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@shanebp - yes I did that, but that shows the 55 word excerpt.

I resolved this as follows ..

I discovered that the excerpt is stored in the WP_Post class field post_excerpt, so I got it directly with ...

```
$the_post = get_post();
$post_excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $the_post->post_excerpt);
echo $post_excerpt;
```

I would be happy to hear from anyone if there is a better way, and also why the_excerpt() doesn't give that field content.

Thanks

Comment: Looking now, the_excerpt should do exactly that, echo $post->post_excerpt filtered through the_excerpt, unless this is a password protected post or unless there is a get_the_excerpt filter that changes the return value.